# How to configure vue.config.js to remove vue-i18n console error when using nm run serve

Tags: vuejs3, vue-i18n

I am very new to Vue and I am trying to set up `vue-i18n` and continue to get console warnings

```
You are running the esm-bundler build of vue-i18n. It is recommended to configure your bundler to explicitly replace feature flag globals with boolean literals to get proper tree-shaking in the final bundle.
```

My process

```
$npm install vue-i18n@next
$npm i --save-dev @intlify/vue-i18n-loader@next
```

I have tried adding different things to my `vue.config.js` file based on various stack overflow answers including

```js
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config =>
    {
        config.module
            .rule( 'i18n' )
            .resourceQuery( /blockType=i18n/ )
            .type( 'javascript/auto' )
            .use( 'i18n' )
            .loader( '@intlify/vue-i18n-loader' )
    }
}
```

and

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack:
    {
        plugins: [
            // Define Bundler Build Feature Flags
            new webpack.DefinePlugin( {
                __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
                __VUE_I18N_FULL_INSTALL__: true,
                __VUE_I18N_LEGACY_API__: true,
                __VUE_I18N_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
                __INTLIFY_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false
            } ),
        ],
    }
};
```

When I use the 1st example `vue.config.js` the global values all log to the console with the correct values, but I still get the warning.

The only thing that seems to remove the error is modifying the `i18n` import.

```js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n/index'
```

However, this seems wrong because it just bypasses the file that generates the warning.

My question boils down too...

How can I configure `vue-i18n` to work with my vue3 project that uses

```
npm run serve
```

in a way that removes the console warning? or What are the exact steps to configure/use/add `vue-i18n` in my vue3 project.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "octo-train-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^6.4.95",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.3",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primevue": "^3.8.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.0.0-rc.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/vue-i18n-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use the second block (the one that uses the `DefinePlugin`? According to the guide, setting those boolean flags explicit should allow tree-shaking: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/optimization.html#reduce-bundle-size-with-feature-build-flags

Comment: if I use the second block they all show as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem, and it seems it is normal IF you are on a dev mode.

https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next/issues/810

You should not see that on a production level

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> The meaning of this warning message is that you need to specify the flag explicitly in the bundler when you do a production build.

Please refer to the following link for packages provided by vue-i18n for bundlers.

https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/installation.html#with-a-bundler

One advice to help you out is to use the plugins for each bundler listed in the NOTE section of the above link, and they will configure them properly for you. I recommend that you check them out.

Checkout this [issue](http://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next/issues/789) listed in GitHub forum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I had followed the advice on that page but I think the part I missed was that it is expected to get the warning in a development environment.

Comment: Please do upvote if it helps you.

Comment: I am unable to upvote sorry, my profile doesn't have the points required.